# ASP.net send password on Email Address

Tags: asp.net, passwords

I have searched about how to do password recovery in case user forgot password but everywhere i have seen people have coded only for g mail , i need example in which all mails are done or some type of general code is written to do that. I want to take user Email as input and send his password on his mail inbox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending e-mail works exactly the same independent of the user's e-mail provider. It's a standard protocol. How did you arrive at the conclusion that the code you've seen online only works with GMail?

Comment: we give the ssl port of gmail, if i apply same code it will work for yahoo and msn also?

Comment: Oh, you were talking about using GMail's SMTP servers to *send* e-mail? Usually you either send mail directly or use your own provider's SMTP server. The same code (in essence) should work with different SMTP servers, but you might need to configure SSL/authentication differently depending on the provider.